# Underscore.js or CoffeeScript idiom for querying multiple object keys?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

I have a parsed query string object, `req.query`, and I want to see if that object has *any* of three keys: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`.

Is there an idiomatic way of querying that with Underscore and/or CoffeeScript?

```
# simple and direct but not very DRY:
if req.query.foo or req.query.bar or req.query.baz
  ..

# using the any filter combined w/ CS's in sugar:
if _(req.query).any (val, key) -> key in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  ..

# plucking just the desired keys:
if _(req.query).pick('foo', 'bar', 'baz').keys().length
  ...
```

Is there another way better than any of these? Either way, what would you write?

Comment: You must mean `pick`, not `pluck`, in that third example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick)?

```
if !_.isEmpty(_(req.query).pick("foo", "bar", "baz"))
  ...
```

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten `isEmpty` works with objects too! Thanks. Would you write it this way over any of the others?

Comment: I guess I'd write it this way, seems the simplest and doesn't depend on coffeescript magic.

Comment: Also, just for (others') reference, I'd write it a bit differently in CS: `if not _.isEmpty _(req.query).pick 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
queryKeys = _.keys(req.query)
if _(queryKeys).intersection(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']).length
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives:

```coffeescript
# Helper function:
# ----------------
_has = (obj, arr) -> (1 for key in arr when obj.hasOwnProperty(key)).length > 0

if _has req.query, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    ...

# Extending `Object`:
# -------------------
Object::has = (arr) ->
    while arr.length && not result = @hasOwnProperty arr.shift() then
    result

if req.query.has ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    ...

# Using native `Array::some`:
# ---------------------------
if ['baz', 'bar', 'foo'].some {}.hasOwnProperty.bind req.query
    # ...
```

Actually I would write this:

```
if (true for key in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] when req.query[k]).length
```

but only if the list is longer than that, otherwise the simple `if query.foo or query.bar or query.baz` wins for clarity and efficiency.